# Drupal 6 - Flag friend module - filtering friended users (or similar)

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I'm using the flag friend module, and I'm trying to accomplish what I thought would be an easy task.

Basically I'm trying to achieve some variation of '**Show all site users in a view, but indicate which ones are the current logged-in user's friends**'. Should be easy I would have thought, but I've spent all day on this and it ain't working. :(

A related option I've tried is to actually filter out the friended users, but I can't get that to work either.

I'm feeling like this question should be more comprehensive, so apologies if that's the case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution isn't elegant, but it'd work...

You can get a set of user objects by using the `flag_friend_get_friends` function and use that to identify friendly users from the view's template.

If you'd prefer get just the friend uids you can query the table directly using

```
db_query('SELECT f.friend_uid FROM {flag_friend} f WHERE f.uid = %d', $user->uid)
```

I'm not super happy with these, but they will work for you.

Hope someone else comes up with something better.

Comment: This looks cool, cheers. OK, to be honest I've got a bit of learning to do in implementing this type of thing... are there any examples you can point me in the direction of? There doesn't seem to be a whole lot of info about flag_friend_get_friends out there!

Comment: I can see the general concept: Get friendly ids, iterate over the rows to check if they match, if so do something to the row.